# PHP variable format

Tags: php

I would like to save the formatting in $temp and print it
But i just get a blank window. see code snippet

```
$temp = number_format((float)$temperature, 1, '.', '') , ' C' ;
echo "$temp" ;
```

Comment: There must be? Or there is? What error?

Comment: Check your logs or turn on error reporting. This is a very simple syntax error - if you wind up on StackOverflow every time you make a typo coding is going to be a very, very slow process.

Comment: I will do a search for turning on "error reporting" , i just started php thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To append a string to the return of your function you need to use `.` not `,`

So like this:

```
$temp = number_format((float)$temperature, 1, '.', '') . ' C' ;
                                                      ^^^^
```